# Is it possible to get singleton mentions by stanford-nlp software?

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

We want to detect the mentions in our data by using the stanford-nlp coref annotator. It seems that the coref annotator does not create singleton chains (i.e. chains with only one mention) by default. Is it possible to configure the annotator so that the resulting annotation contains the signleton chains in addition to the non-singleton ones.

Thank you.

Comment: We know that it is possible to get singleton mentions if we use the deterministic coref resolution system (i.e. the annotator is "dcoref"). The question is, is it possible to get the "1-member" coref chains with statistical or neural systems as well?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you define entities, you can use the POS tagger or the phrase chunker to get the outstanding "1-member" coref chains.